# Android SQLite delete() all and return value

Tags: android, sqlite

This is a short snippet I found:

> "Deleting data
>
> Once data is no longer needed it can be removed from the database with
>   the delete() method. The delete() method expects 3 parameters, the
>   database name, a WHERE clause, and an argument array for the WHERE
>   clause. To delete all records from a table pass null for the WHERE
>   clause and WHERE clause argument array.
>
> db.delete("tbl_states", "id=?", new String[] {Long.toString(countryId)});
>
> Simply call the delete() method to remove records from the SQLite database. The delete method expects, the table name, and optionally a
>   where clause and where clause argument replacement arrays as
>   parameters. The where clause and argument replacement array work just
>   as with update where ? is replaced by the values in the array."

As usual I cannot find simple documentation as to:

1. How do I delete *everything* in the given table (I do not want to use .execSQL) via the .delete() method
2. What does it return? A cursor or interger? boolean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passing in `null` to the WHERE clause and argument array will delete everything (think if there is no WHERE clause all you are saying is `delete from tbl_states`).

`delete` returns the number of rows deleted as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

This line, from your description, answers your first question:

> ...To delete all records from a table pass null for the WHERE clause
>   and WHERE clause argument array

```
db.delete("tbl_states", null, null);
```

The second answer: it returns the number of rows affected (or deleted, in integer)  from the table. Say, you have 20 records in your "tbl_states" table, then, firing the above query will return 20 as integer.

```
int values = db.delete("tbl_states", null, null);
```

Comment: You are absolutly correct about question number 1. DOH! Talk about missing the last line!