# Android Room Bulk Delete with Keys

Tags: android, persistence, android-room

I have a table of objects I have previously populated and a new list of several thousand ids for objects that should be in the table. I would like to delete each object in the table in the case that its primary key is not present in the list of ids. Basically a bulk delete to get rid of the old items. Is there a simple way to do this with Room? I'm not seeing it in the documentation but perhaps I've overlooked it.

To be more clear, my list of ids is a list of items I DO NOT want to delete and are more than the 999 sql limit for variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can always run a custom query using Room. Maybe you can do something as follows?

```
@Query("delete from old_table where id not in (:ids)")
int deleteOldItems(int[] ids);
```

**Edit:**

Because of the number of data that are going to be matched and deleted, the query above will not serve your purpose if you are splitting your queries.

If I understood the problem correctly, here's something that you might consider doing.

1. Get the list of ids that are already present in your old table.
2. Compare that list with the new id list that you have. You should be able to find the ids that are needed to be deleted from the table.
3. Then run a delete query with the ids (existing - new)
4. Then create new entries in the table with the list of newly added items.

You can also split both delete and insert operations in 3rd and 4th step as they are not conflicting operations.

Comment: At this moment I don't have two tables. There is just the original table and a List<String> of ids. I'd rather not make a second table if not necessary as this List is only used once, for this purpose, and then discarded. Is there another way?

Comment: You can just pass the list of ids that you want to delete as a parameter to this function in that case. I am not sure if I am understanding correctly, but let me update the query in the answer.

Comment: Is the int being returned the number of rows deleted?

Comment: Yeah, that should be it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24235553/3145960

Comment: This failed because SQL will only accept 999 variables at a time.

Comment: The workaround is splitting the request. Right?

Comment: That sounds great but how? I have a table and a List<String> that numbers in the several thousands. If I split the list into chunks of 999 items or smaller then when I bump it up against the table all the items other than the original 999 would be deleted from the table. Is there another way I'm missing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228906/discussion-between-joel-nieman-and-reaz-murshed).